# UITableView didSelectRowForIndexPath, not animating selection and deselection of checkmark

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've done this before, but am having trouble getting it to work again.  In any case, at my model class I basically have a dictionary that has two items for Sorting, and I want only one value to be YES, and the others to be NO.  I want the selection of the item in the UITableViewCell to reflect that and animate the selection and deselection.  So at the model class, I have this method that just changes the other value that was selected to false:

```
- (void)setSingleSort:(NSString *)key {
    for (NSString *str in [_sortOrderDictionary allKeys]) {
        if (str != key) {
            [_sortOrderDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:str];
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have this snippet in my didSelectRowForIndexPath method:

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];

NSString *key;
BOOL valueAtKey;
    key = [_sortCategoryList objectAtIndex:row];
    valueAtKey = [[dmgr.SortOrderDictionary valueForKey:key] boolValue];
    if (valueAtKey != YES) {
        [dmgr.SortOrderDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!valueAtKey] forKey:key];
        [dmgr setSingleSort:key];
        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_lastIndexPath];
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:_lastIndexPath animated:YES];
    }
    _lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadData]; //Edited, added this to the end and it seems to work.  Don't know why it's needed though since the deslectRowAtIndexPath should animated, along with the setSelected:Animated: right?
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your selectionStyle is the reason.  This is normally how I go about doing this.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
//create new or fetch dequeued cell
if((indexPath.row == self.indexPathOfCurrentValue.row) && (indexPath.section == self.indexPathOfCurrentValue.section))
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

then in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, do something like this:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

//APP RELATED LOGIC GOES HERE

if(nil != self.indexPathOfCurrentValue)
     [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPathOfCurrentValue] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

self.indexPathOfCurrentValue = indexPath;
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPathOfCurrentValue] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckMark];
```

This is normally the approach I take when I need to checkmark the row on user's tap and uncheck the last selected row.  Obviously, the currentValue index path variables holds the lastest checkmark's index path.

Comment: hm, if I just do a [tableView reloadData] at the end, it seems to work.  Don't know why it's needed though in this case since the animations should work right?

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of this line:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```